# Browser memory consumption keeps increasing when open a GCP notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

My browser memory consumption keeps increasing (then eventually dies) when I open a Google Cloud Platform notebook.
[image]

What can I do to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is still some information needed, Notebook version, browser version, what are you doing when this happens? Running a cell. How often, how long it takes to die.

Comment: @Doung NGUYEN can you please reply this comment ^

Answer (score -1):

If your Google browser occupies more memory, you have few ways to check and decrease the memory usage.

1. If your browser was running for many days and no clean up was done recently , you can try to check and remove old data.

**Go to run > %appdata% > navigate to appdata folder > local > google > chrome > user data >** here you are able to see the **default** folder. Now you can sync your data to your personal email and check if it's sync or not. If it's sync you can delete the folder or you can rename the folder. Also you can end the chrome process before renaming or deleting the folder.

If you rename the default folder, you can save your old data as well. Now you can open the browser once again and sign in with your credentials and also check the memory utilization now.

2. You may previously allow more applications / extensions to run in background, check and close it if possible.

**Go to settings > more tools > task manager >** here you can find which extensions are taking more memory. Now you have an idea which extensions are taking more memory and you can try to disable it If you're not using those extensions.

To disable the extensions Go to settings > more tools > extensions > you can disable the extensions which you're not using and remove it if possible.

You can also use this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4F7tKh4BUE) for your reference and follow the steps to reduce the high memory utilization on chrome.

Comment: @Duong NGUYEN, Is this above solution is helped you to solve your issue?

Comment: @Takikonda wamsikrishna: thank you for your answer, however, it didn't solve the problem.